# R | readLine | read file containing numbers only (separated by whitespace)

Tags: r, numeric, readline

I am reading a file where in each line there are numbers separated by spaces.

I am using following command

```
f <- file("stdin")

on.exit(close(f))

L <- strsplit(readLines(f), "\n")

T1 <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(L[[1]], split = "\\s"))) # to read line containing numbers separated by spaces.
```

Is there any optimal way to do without using any external libraries ?

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: For each line I need to cast it as numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file contents matches its posted description, `scan` will read in numbers automatically.

```
f <- file('test.txt', open = 'rt')
x <- scan(f)
```

> Read 9 items

```
close(f)

x
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

**File `test.txt`.**

The file is a Ubuntu 19.10 text file, lines end with `'\n'`. Numbers are separated by spaces, not necessarily just one space.

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 
7  8 9
```

## Edit

Note that this also works with non integers. I have edited the file above to include a number `3.14`.

```
f <- file('test2.txt', open = 'rt')
x <- scan(f)
```

> Read 9 items

```
close(f)

x
#[1] 1.00 2.00 3.14 4.00 5.00 6.00 7.00 8.00 9.00
```

**File `test2.txt`.**

```
1 2 3.14 4
5 6 
7  8 9
```

Comment: Wonder what the benefits are of *file-scan-close* vs directly `scan(file = "test2.txt")`?

Comment: @sindri_baldur The question uses `file` to create the connection. I don't know whether it is a simplified example of a more complicated use case so I have opted to use the same sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Trivially, if each line in your input CSV contain the same number of terms, then you may just use `read.csv`:

```
f <- "path/to/your/input.csv"
T1 <- read.csv(file=f, sep=" ")  # using space as a separator
```

If each line could contain a variable count of numbers, then your current approach is acceptable.

Comment: @Gaurav Then specify space as being the separator, using the `sep` argument to `read.csv`.